# Constrain C# generic parameter with interface implementations

Tags: c#, generics

To illustrate my question I've written a simple method:

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(...)
    where T : ISomeInterface
{
    // return an instance of T
}
```

Obviously this method can be called like

```
ConvertTo<ISomeInterface>(...)
```

But in my case it doesn't make sense. Method should return an instance of a class that implements `ISomeInterface`. At now I throw `NotSupportedException` for any type the method unable to work with and I satisfied with this solution. But if I could filter out an interface itself in compile time it would be better.

**So my question is**: Is it possible to constrain generic parameter with **implementations** of an interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is: Is it possible to constrain generic parameter with implementations of an interface?

No, there is not. You have found the best-fitting solutions: `class` and `new()`, where `class` only filters out structs, etc. `class` *and* `new()` used together is the only real solution, but a solution that is actually too strict.

You might have some luck with code analyzers or AOP where can filter out bad calls on compile-time.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, `new()` is too strict. At now it seems that throwing an exception in run-time is a good solution. But I will think about creating parameterless constructors for my types because to have compile-time checks is better for me.